# Why does `last` show '{' and '|' in the TTY field?

Tags: freebsd, tty, last

We recently set up a new FreeBSD 7.2 machine on March 11. When looking at `last`, we noticed some funny characters for the TTY field.

What do these characters mean? Note that at this time, the sysadmin was battling with NTP.

```
# last |grep date
date             {                         Fri Mar 10 17:26
date             |                         Fri Mar 10 15:26
date             {                         Fri Mar 10 15:26
date             |                         Fri Mar 10 03:14
date             {                         Fri Mar 10 03:11
date             |                         Sat Mar 11 15:22
date             {                         Sat Mar 11 15:21
date             |                         Sat Mar 11 09:20
```

And according to `man last`, I can specify the tty using `-t tty`:

```
# last -t {
date             {                         Fri Mar 10 17:26
date             {                         Fri Mar 10 15:26
date             {                         Fri Mar 10 03:11
date             {                         Sat Mar 11 15:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `utmp(5)`:

```
The system time has been manually or automatically updated (see
date(1)).  The command name date is recorded in the field
ut_name.  In the field ut_line, the character `|' indicates the
time prior to the change, and the character `{' indicates the
new time.
```

So the I and { are just there to indicate that the system time is being changed.